# Hot Chocolate (Entity Framework) is not following many-to-many links

Tags: .net-core, graphql, entity-framework-core, hotchocolate

I can't seem to get Hot Chocolate's `[UseProjection]` to follow many-to-many links. What am I missing?

The data comes from PostgreSQL via Entity Framework Core 7. My DB has `offer` and `channel` tables, with a many-to-many relationship via a link table. I reverse-engineered my entity classes with `Scaffold-DbContext`, so there is no class for the link table.

If I use Entity Framework to query channels with associated offers:

```
context.Channels.Include(_ => _.Offers).ToList();
```

it joins the tables and includes the offers the way I would expect:

```
  SELECT c.channel_id, c.description, c.name, t.channel_id, t.offer_code, t.offer_code0, t.description, t.name, t.status
  FROM channel AS c
  LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT c0.channel_id, c0.offer_code, o.offer_code AS offer_code0, o.description, o.name, o.status
      FROM "Channel_Offer" AS c0
      INNER JOIN offer AS o ON c0.offer_code = o.offer_code
  ) AS t ON c.channel_id = t.channel_id
  ORDER BY c.channel_id, t.channel_id, t.offer_code
```

But using Hot Chocolate with this query:

```
query {
  channels {
    name
    offers {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

and this query class (set up with
`AddGraphQLServer().RegisterDbContext<MyDbContext>().AddProjections()`):

```
[ExtendObjectType("Query")]
public class ChannelQuery
{
    [UseProjection]
    public IQueryable<Channel> GetChannels([Service] MyDbContext context)
    => context.Channels;
}
```

it *doesn't* try to join the tables:

```
  SELECT c.name AS "Name"
  FROM channel AS c
```

so the returned `offers` list is empty. (I tried returning `context.Channels.Include(_ => _.Offers)` from the query, but that made no difference.)

**Is there some setup I am missing?** I presume the context setup etc is OK, since the `context.Channels.Include(_ => _.Offers).ToList()` works properly; it's just that HC is not using the queryable to follow the links.

Comment: You just should return `context.Channels` the include is done by Hot Chocolate.

BTW, are you using dotnet 6 or 7?

Comment: @MichaelIngmarStaib Thanks for your reply -- it makes no difference if I remove the `.Include` -- I originally wasn't using it but I added it in to see if it made a difference. BTW I am using dotnet 6.

Comment: I edited the question to clarify the above, and also to mention that I reverse-engineered my entity classes with Scaffold-DbContext, so there is no class for the link table. But that's perfectly fine and normal and EF is happy with it, so you'd think HC would work too.

Comment: As I mentioned, if I return `context.Channels.Include(_ => _.Offers)` from the resolver, the tables are *not* joined... *unless* I also remove `[UseProjection]` in which case they are *always* joined (as expected), even when they don't need to be. It looks very much as if Hot Chocolate's Projection is not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the entity classes generated by `Scaffold-DbContext`. For example, this is the generated `Channel.Offers` field:

```
public virtual ICollection<Offer> Offers { get; } = new List<Offer>();
```

But [Hot Chocolate's Projections documentation](https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/v12/fetching-data/projections) states:

> Projections currently need a public setter on fields they operate on in order to function correctly. Otherwise the default constructed value will be returned upon query.

The queries started working when I added a setter to the generated class:

```
public virtual ICollection<Offer> Offers { get; set; } = new List<Offer>();
```

I'll have to remember to add it back if I ever need to regenerate the entity classes.